# So I moved from Ubuntu to Kubuntu and I get the default login screen

Tags: kubuntu, login

So I switched to Kubuntu with this command: `sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop` and everything works fine except one thing: the login screen. The login screen is the default one and I don't know how to change it. I tried a few guides but they don't seem to work.

Comment: @DKBose That worked! Thanks!

Comment: @DKBose can you please comment as an answer so that i can mark this as answered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, Ubuntu uses GDM3 (GNOME Display Manager) whereas Kubuntu uses SDDM (Simple Desktop Display Manager).

When you added kubuntu-desktop, you may have been offered the option to select either display manager and you may have chosen GDM3.

Now that you want SDDM, simply run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm
```

See https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/12/how-to-change-default-display-manager.html.